# module tensorflow has no attribute get default graph

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn

I am getting the following error, i don't know what it means. I am trying to follow this person's instruction from youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbWamLW0_wU

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
cvscores = []
for train, test in kfold.split(X_new, y_res):
#create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(200, input_dim=X_new.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(400, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation ='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss= 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
#Fit the model and create a checkpoint
#checkpoint_path = "training/cp.ckpt"
#checkpoint_dir= os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
#cp_callback = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_path, save_weights_only = True,verbose=1)
model.fit(X_new[train], y_res[train], epochs=100, verbose=0)
# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_new[test], y_res[test], verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
cvscores.append(scores[1]*100)
print("%.2f%%(+/- %.2f%%)" % (np.mean(cvscores), np.std(cvscores)))"
```

I am getting the error as in the attachment:[it says module tensorflow has no attribute get_default_graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPQco.png)

**UPDATE:**

I changed the versions to tensorflow 1.13.2 and keras 2.1.2 and I am now getting an error like this:

> WARNING:tensorflow:From
>   C:\Users\jrnja\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py:263:
>   colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and
>   will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating:
>   Colocations handled automatically by placer.
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:From
>   C:\Users\jrnja\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py:3066:
>   to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will
>   be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use tf.cast
>   instead.

Comment: It's better to put error text in the question rather than a screenshot. What is the version of tensorflow? Are you using `keras` or `tf.keras`?

Comment: You are using TensorFlow 2.0 with a version of Keras that does not support TensorFlow 2.0

Comment: @Mehraban changed the versions to tensorflow 1.13.2 and keras 2.1.2 and I am now getting an error like this:

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Thank you , I changed the version and am getting a warning now.